# Programmatically get the location of a block in AutoCAD with its ObjectId

Tags: c#, autocad-plugin

I'm trying to write a method to change an existing block in an AutoCAD drawing. In this case, I want to change the length of a block by changing its scale factors. The method I've written will accomplish that by deleting the old block and creating a new one with the newly desired scale factors.

```
        private static ObjectId _adjustCapPlate(ObjectId capPlateID, bool isHorizontal, Distance left = null, Distance right = null)
        {
            BlockReference capPlate = EntityMethods.GetBlockById(capPlateID); //Getting the block to be replaced
            Scale3d oldScales = capPlate.ScaleFactors; //Getting the scales of the old block
            Point3d originalLocation = capPlate.Location; // ToDo: Replace capPlate.Location with code that will return the coordinates of the insertion point of the block
            EntityMethods.DeleteBlockFromDrawingWithId(capPlate.Id); //Deleting the old block
            //Using specified splice plate length if method does not specify something else
            if (left == null)
            {
                left = new Distance(SettingsController.SplicePlateLength / 2);
            }
            if (right == null)
            {
                right = new Distance(SettingsController.SplicePlateLength);
            }

            Distance newXScale, newYScale, newZScale;
            Point3d newLocation;

            if (isHorizontal) //If wall is oriented horizontally
            {
                newXScale = new Distance(DistanceType.Inch, oldScales.X - right.Inches);
                newYScale = new Distance(DistanceType.Inch, oldScales.Y);
                newLocation = new Point3d(originalLocation.X + left.Inches, originalLocation.Y, originalLocation.Z);
            }
            else
            {
                newXScale = new Distance(DistanceType.Inch, oldScales.X);
                newYScale = new Distance(DistanceType.Inch, oldScales.Y - right.Inches);
                newLocation = new Point3d(originalLocation.X, originalLocation.Y + left.Inches, originalLocation.Z);
            }
            newZScale = new Distance(DistanceType.Inch, oldScales.Z);

            BlockReference newCapPlate = EntityMethods.InsertBlock("member", newLocation, "0", null, newXScale, newYScale, newZScale);
        }
```

All I need to make this method to work is to replace capPlate.Location with something that will get an existing block's XYZ coordinates in the AutoCAD drawing. It seems ridiculous that there is no obvious way to get a block's coordinates programmatically.

I will not accept answers that change my approach. This has to be done by deleting the old block and replacing it by inserting a new block with new properties where the old block was.

Comment: Is it [`BlockReference.Position`](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2015/05/jigging-an-autocad-block-with-attributes-using-net-redux.html)?

Comment: What exactly do you need - the location of the insertion point, the upper-left point of the circumscribed rectangle around the block or other point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `capPlate.Location`, use `capPlate.Position` and you should get the desired behavior.

Comment: yeah the API is funny and inconsistent. some places you need location other places you need position. it's inconsistent and restricts polymorphic programming